# Java: reflection on grandchild class attributes

Tags: java, inheritance, reflection

I'm facing an issue while trying to use Java reflection.

I have a PermanentObject class, that implements a general method to turn an object into a JSON string (the syntax is not yet completely implemented so glide past it)

This is the code of the method:

```
@Override
public String toFileFormat() {
        String info = "";
        
        try {
            
            Class myClass = this.getClass();
            Class mySuperclass = myClass.getSuperclass();
            Field[] superclassFields = mySuperclass.getDeclaredFields();
            Field[] myFields = myClass.getDeclaredFields();
            
            info += "{\n";
            
            for (int i = 0; i < superclassFields.length; i++) {
                myFields[i].setAccessible(true);
                info += "\"" + superclassFields[i].getName() + "\":\"" + superclassFields[i].get(this) + "\",\n";
            }
            
            for (int i = 0; i < myFields.length; i++) {
                myFields[i].setAccessible(true);
                info += "\"" + myFields[i].getName() + "\":\"" + myFields[i].get(this) + "\"";
                if (i < myFields.length - 1) info += ",";
                info += "\n";
            }
            
            info += "}";
            
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        
        return info;
}
```

I then have a User abstract subclass that extends PermanentObject, and a Professor subclass that extends User.

When invoking the method tho I get this error:
`java.lang.IllegalAccessException: class esercizio2.permanence.PermanentObject cannot access a member of class esercizio2.logic.users.User with modifiers "private"`

I was wondering why this is

I can solve the problem by implementing the method in the User class rather than in the PermanentObject class, but this leads to duplication of code since there are other PermanentObject subclasses that will need to use this.

Thanks for the help :>

Comment: You are calling `myFields[i].setAccessible(true);` in the loop for the superclass' fields, maybe it is just a typo?

Comment: Wow I can't believe it man that was indeed the problem thanks a bunch

Comment: You should be aware that classes can have fields with the same name. And that letting Reflection determine the persistent format is a bad idea in general. This will break on the slightest changes of the classes’ internals.

Answer (score 0):

As you mentioned, moving the toFileFormat method to the User class (or any other subclass) is a good solution. This allows each subclass to implement its own behavior for converting objects to JSON while avoiding the issue of accessing private fields. If there is common code that needs to be shared among subclasses, you can create a helper method in the superclass (e.g., PermanentObject) that the subclasses can call.

Also instead of directly accessing fields through reflection, you can provide public getter methods for the fields you want to include in your JSON representation. This way, you can access the values without violating encapsulation.